# Meteor Autoform package with collection2 does not submit the form

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using using collection2 and autoform with one level nested schemas

```
Node = new Meteor.Collection('node',{
schema: new SimpleSchema({
       content: {
           type: String,
           label: "Content",
           max: 200
       }
       created: {
           type: Date,
           label: "Created Date"
       },
       modified: {
           type: Date,
           label: "Modified Date"
       }
   })
});

NodeMeta = new Meteor.Collection('Node_meta',{
schema: new SimpleSchema({
    desc:{
        type:String,
        max:200,
        label:"Description",
        optional:true
    }
})

});

Schema = {};

Schema.nodeWithMeta= new SimpleSchema({
  Node: {
     type: Node.simpleSchema()
  },
  Meta: {
     type: NodeMeta.simpleSchema()
  }
});


{{#autoForm schema=schema id="nodeForm" type="method" meteormethod="nodecreate"}}
  {{> afFieldInput name='Node.content' rows=8 }}
  {{> afFieldInput name='Meta.desc' rows=8}}    
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit">Create</button>
{{/autoForm}}

Template.nodeCreate.helpers({
  schema: function() {
    return Schema.nodeWithMeta;
  }
});
```

It does not call server method. I tried autoform onSubmit hook as well as Meteors inbuilt templates 'submit' event handler. If I use jQuery onsubmit event handler, it registers the event. I cannot use jQuery for this purpose since autoform has to validate the inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Since `created` and `modified` are required fields, it's most likely not submitting because those fields are missing from the form, which means the form is invalid. There are actually a few different ways you can solve this:

1. Make them optional (probably not what you want)
2. Use a different schema, one without those two fields, for the `schema` attribute of the autoform.
3. Add a "before method" hook that sets those two fields in the submitted doc.
4. Use `autoValue` to generate the values for those two fields.

Since created and modified dates are fairly easy to do with [autoValue](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#autovalue), I would do it that way. Something like this:

```
created: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Created Date",
    autoValue: function () {
        if (this.isInsert) {
          return new Date;
        } else {
          this.unset();
        }
    }
},
modified: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Modified Date",
    autoValue: function () {
        if (this.isInsert) {
          this.unset();
        } else {
          return new Date;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, to help figure out issues like this more easily while developing, I recommend enabling [debug mode](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#debug-mode).

Comment: Now I changed the form submission a little bit. I am using onSubmit instead of form's type="method". I want to insert data from client-side. But since my doc schema has nested schemas i.e doc.Node and doc.Meta, it throws an error 
  `code`  - line 299 SimpleSchema.js> Uncaught: TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'pushAll' in undefined. `code`

Comment: It should throw a better error, but that means that somehow it's calling simpleSchema.clean, but passing in `undefined` for the first argument. It would be best to submit an issue on GitHub and include a link to a repo that reproduces the error.

Comment: Its not passing undefined but directly passing my complex doc object into its clean functions. It accepts doc object, but since my form schema is made out of two merged schemas, its passing doc.Meta.desc and doc.Node.content in one doc object.

Comment: That's to be expected because subschemas are actually merged into a single schema by the constructor. It shouldn't make any difference with how it's validated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you allowed inserts/updates on your collection? See http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity.

I bet if you run the two commands below, it'll work.

```
meteor add insecure
meteor add autopublish
```

Now try your submit.

If it does work, turn autopublish and insecure back off

```
meteor remove insecure
meteor remove autopublish
```

Then write your allow methods, e.g.

```
Node.allow({
  insert: function (userId, nodeDoc) {
    // write some logic to allow the insert 
    return true;
  }
});
```